# Concatinate all matching names dynamically | Google sheets

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, concatenation, flatten, textjoin

I want to get the concatenation of the input names according to value like this `Name1, Name2,...`

I tryed this formula but i need to be **dynamic** with **`Arrayformula`**.
[***Make a copy***](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1T1QiCVE_G94X--uG56HxYVVJuKU2P8H0AVQgz13a-lM/copy) of this example

```
=IF(D3="",,TEXTJOIN(", ",1,FILTER($A$3:$A,$B$3:$B=D3)))
```

[image]

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) [Why are images of text, code and mathematical expressions discouraged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320052/266284)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all you need is:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(SPLIT(FLATTEN(QUERY(QUERY(
 FILTER({A3:A&",", B3:B&"×"}, B3:B<>""), 
 "select max(Col1) group by Col1 pivot Col2"),,9^9)), "×")), ",$", ))
```

[image]